# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined [ngrx entity example with effects - firebase]

Tags: angular, firebase, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

### Minimal reproduction of the bug/regression with instructions:

Have a look on the repo https://github.com/mappedinn/ng-ngrx-entity-pizza-firebase-effects:

- install the npm packages `npm i`
- open this link http://localhost:4200/pizza
- check the console

### Expected behavior:

This is how my reducer is defined:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: PizzaActions): PizzaState {
  switch (action.type) {

    case PizzaActionTypes.PIZZA_ADDED:
      // if there is one pizza added in the backend, so the store has to be added
      console.log('action=');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(action));
      console.log('action.payload=');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(action.paylaod));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(action['paylaod']));
      // return pizzaAdaptor.addOne({id: '003', size: 'medium', status: 'cooking'}, state);
      return pizzaAdaptor.addOne(action.paylaod, state);

    case PizzaActionTypes.PIZZA_MODIFED:
      // if there is one pizza being modified in the backend, so the store has to modify it
      return pizzaAdaptor.updateOne({
        id: action.paylaod.id,
        changes: action.paylaod
      }, state);

    case PizzaActionTypes.PIZZA_REMOVED:
      // if there is one pizza being removed in the backend, so the store has to remove it
      return pizzaAdaptor.removeOne(action.paylaod.id, state);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am getting the error below for the pizza reducer:

> core.js:1624 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at selectId (http://localhost:4200/app-modules-pizza-pizza-module.js:424:94)
>       at addOneMutably (http://localhost:4200/app-modules-pizza-pizza-module.js:124:19)
>       at Object.operation [as addOne] (http://localhost:4200/app-modules-pizza-pizza-module.js:101:25)
>       at reducer (http://localhost:4200/app-modules-pizza-pizza-module.js:873:33)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77764:20
>       at combination (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77722:35)
>       at computeNextEntry (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77058:21)
>       at recomputeStates (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77089:15)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77316:30
>       at ScanSubscriber.StoreDevtools.liftedAction$.pipe.Object.state [as accumulator] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77381:38)

This made me think the action is probably undefined. A `console.log(JSON.stringify(action))`  check show this:

> action=
>
> {"type":"[Pizza] added","payload":{"id":"001","size":"big","status":"cooking"}}

Since the reducer is adding a new entity to the store through `pizzaAdaptor.addOne(action.paylaod, state);`, I checked also `action.payload` through `console.log(JSON.stringify(action.paylaod));` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(action['paylaod']));`. The result is as follows:

> action.payload=
>
> undefined
>
> action['payload']=
>
> undefined

The action object in the reducer is behaving **strangely**.

**PS:** The error disappear if I set manually the `action.payload` object as follows `return pizzaAdaptor.addOne({id: '003', size: 'medium', status: 'cooking'}, state);`

### Versions of NgRx, Angular, Node, affected browser(s) and operating system(s):

```
$ npm -v
6.1.0
$ node -v
v8.11.2
$ uname -a
# Linux X580VD 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 13 08:44:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ npm ls --depth 0
ng-ngrx-entity-pizza-firebase-effects@0.0.0 /home/amine/docker-projects/ng-ngrx-entity-pizza-firebase-effects
├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.8
├── @angular/animations@6.0.7
├── @angular/cli@6.0.8
├── @angular/common@6.0.7
├── @angular/compiler@6.0.7
├── @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.7
├── @angular/core@6.0.7
├── @angular/forms@6.0.7
├── @angular/http@6.0.7
├── @angular/language-service@6.0.7
├── @angular/platform-browser@6.0.7
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.0.7
├── @angular/router@6.0.7
├── @ngrx/effects@6.0.1
├── @ngrx/entity@6.0.1
├── @ngrx/schematics@6.0.1
├── @ngrx/store@6.0.1
├── @ngrx/store-devtools@6.0.1
├── @types/jasmine@2.8.8
├── @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
├── @types/node@8.9.5
├── angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11
├── codelyzer@4.2.1
├── core-js@2.5.7
├── firebase@5.2.0
├── jasmine-core@2.99.1
├── jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
├── karma@1.7.1
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
├── karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.1
├── karma-jasmine@1.1.2
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
├── protractor@5.3.2
├── rxjs@6.2.1
├── ts-node@5.0.1
├── tslint@5.9.1
├── typescript@2.7.2
└── zone.js@0.8.26
```

### Other information:

The obtained error is similar to https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/645#issuecomment-351787150

The tutorial I used for building the pizza reducer is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rv37jBygQ2g&list=PL0vfts4VzfNjrI4e_cJmqfSrUvaBADMlD&index=5

Thank you very much for helping me to solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the reducer. I'm guessing you want `action.payload.id` instead of `action.paylaod.id`. Looks like there are a few places where this needs changing

Comment: You are absolutely right...